# How can I "map" in ORMLite a base object that all Database entities extend

Tags: android, annotations, ormlite, object-persistence

I have an object that I call `BaseObject` which all classes that are persisted extend. This class has an `_id` field, `dateCreated`, `dateModified`, etc.... The database tables that correspond to all objects that extends this base object obviously have columns that store these values.

How can I set up these fields using annotations so all these fields are persisted to the database? Can I do this or will I need to add these fields to the POJOs directly? I have included below my base object and one of the classes that extends it.

```
public class BaseObject {
    private int _id;
    private String dateCreated;
    private String dateModified;
    private String createModule;
    private String modifiedModule;

    // getters and setters here ... 
}
```

Here's the super-class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "FOOD")
public class Food extends BaseObject {

    public Food(int foodGroupId, String longDescription) {
        this.foodGroupId = foodGroupId;
        this.longDescription = longDescription;
    }

    private Integer foodGroupId;
    private String longDescription;

    // getters and setters here ... 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This should work well with [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) as long as you annotate each of the fields in both the base-class *and* the super-class that you want persisted.  For example, you need to need to add something like the following annotations to the `BaseObject`.

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int _id;
@DatabaseField
private String dateCreated;
@DatabaseField
private String dateModified;
@DatabaseField
private String createModule;
@DatabaseField
private String modifiedModule;
```

And then you add the following annotations to the super-class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "FOOD")
public class Food extends BaseObject {

    @DatabaseField
    private Integer foodGroupId;
    @DatabaseField
    private String longDescription;
```